# how to fix org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException and org.hibernate.WrongClassException: with faktor ips

Tags: hibernate, persistence, faktor-ips

I'm trying to add persistence to a faktor ips project that is based on the intro tutorial from https://www.faktorzehn.org. I have a model object that looks like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Angebot {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private Integer id;
    private String angebotNr;
    private String produktname;
    private LocalDate wirksamAb;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private HausratVertrag hausratVertrag;

    /**
     * Erstellt ein neues Angebot {@code Angebot} f�r das gew�hlte
     * Hausrat-Produkt zu dem angegeben Wirksamkeitsdatum.
     * 
     * @param angebotNr
     *            eine Angebotsnummer.
     * @param hausratProdukt
     *            ein Hausratprodukt.
     * @param wirksamkeitsdatum
     *            das Wirksamkeitsdatum.
     */
    
    public Angebot(String angebotNr,HausratProdukt hausratProdukt, LocalDate wirksamAb) {
        this.angebotNr = angebotNr;
        this.wirksamAb = wirksamAb;
    }
    
    public Angebot() {}

    public String getAngebotNr() {
        return angebotNr;
    }

    public void setAngebotNr(String angebotNr) {
        this.angebotNr = angebotNr;
    }

    public String getProduktname() {
        return produktname;
    }

    public void setProduktname(String produktname) {
        this.produktname = produktname;
    }

    public LocalDate getWirksamAb() {
        return wirksamAb;
    }

    public void setWirksamAb(LocalDate wirksamAb) {
        this.wirksamAb = wirksamAb;
    }

    /**
     * Liefert den Hausratvertrag
     * 
     * @return Hausratvertrag
     */
    public HausratVertrag getHausratVertrag() {
        return hausratVertrag;
    }

    public void setHausratVertrag(HausratVertrag hausratVertrag) {
        this.hausratVertrag = hausratVertrag;
    }


    @Transient
    private HausratProdukt selectedProdukt;
    public HausratProdukt getProdukt() {
        if (produktname !=null) {
            IProductComponent pc = Utils.getRuntimeRepository().getProductComponent(this.getProduktname());
            return (HausratProdukt) pc;
        }else {
            return selectedProdukt;
        }
    }
    
    public void setProdukt(HausratProdukt selectedProduct) {
        this.selectedProdukt = selectedProduct;
    }
    

    /**
     * Berechnet die Beitraege neu und
     */
    public void neuBerechnen() {
        hausratVertrag.berechneJahresbasisbeitrag();
    }
    
    

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("Angebot(produktName=").append(getProdukt().getProduktName()).append(")");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
}
```

the database has three tables

ANGEBOT:
|ID | ANGEBOT_NR | PRODUKTNAME| HAUSRAT_VERTRAG_ID|
|---|------------|------------|-------------------|
|33 |kompakt     | beispiel.HR-Kompakt 2022-01|33|
VERTRAG:
|Typ | ID | PRODUKT_CONFIGURATION|
|----|----|----------------------|
|HRV |33  | ...                  |
DECKUNG:
|Typ         | ID | PRODUKT_CONFIGURATION|VERTRAG_ID|
|------------|----|----------------------|----------|
|HRG_DECKUNG |33  | ...                  |33|

basically how the project works is that a Contract (hausratVertrag) can have one base coverage(Grunddeckung - marked with typ = HRG_DECKUNG in the database) and 0 or many extra coverages (Zusatsdeckung - marked with typ = HRZ_DECKUNG in database, but my database doesn't have any saved). The object "Angebot" has a one to one relationship with HausratVertrag, and HausratVertrag has a one to one with HausratGrunddeckung and a one to many with HausratZusatzdeckung. Like so:

```java
    /**
     * Membervariable fuer die Beziehung HausratGrunddeckung.
     * 
     * @since 0.0.1
     *
     * @generated NOT
     * @customizedAnnotations CONTENT-CHANGED
     */
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "hausratVertrag", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = HausratGrunddeckung.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private HausratGrunddeckung hausratGrunddeckung = null;
    /**
     * Membervariable fuer die Beziehung HausratZusatzdekung.
     * 
     * @since 0.0.1
     *
     * @generated
     * 
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "hausratVertrag", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = HausratZusatzdekung.class)
    private List<HausratZusatzdekung> hausratZusatzdekungen = new ArrayList<>();
```

My problem is that when I try to load an "Angebot" from the database I get the following error.

```
com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager$RpcInvocationException: Unable to invoke method click in com.vaadin.shared.ui.button.ButtonServerRpc
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:159)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:116)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:442)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:407)
    
...

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:155)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method buttonClick in org.linkki.core.ui.aspects.ButtonInvokeAspectDefinition$$Lambda$300/0x0000000800812440 failed.
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:726)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:399)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:363)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1190)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:384)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.model.hasurat.HausratVertrag.hausratZusatzdekungen, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:587)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:261)
    at org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.model.hasurat.HausratVertrag.getNumOfHausratZusatzdekungen(HausratVertrag.java:467)
    at org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.model.hasurat.HausratVertrag.getNumOfDeckungenInternal(HausratVertrag.java:623)
    at org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.model.hasurat.HausratVertrag.getDeckungen(HausratVertrag.java:597)
    at org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.page.VertragPage.<init>(VertragPage.java:39)
    at org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.view.VertragView.enter(VertragView.java:43)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.performNavigateTo(Navigator.java:778)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.lambda$navigateTo$9a874efd$1(Navigator.java:702)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.ViewBeforeLeaveEvent.navigate(ViewBeforeLeaveEvent.java:54)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.View.beforeLeave(View.java:79)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.runAfterLeaveConfirmation(Navigator.java:730)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:701)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:678)
    at org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.pmo.AngebotSectionPmo.send(AngebotSectionPmo.java:83)
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.InvokeMethod.invoke(InvokeMethod.java:61)
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.PropertyAccessor.invoke(PropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.ReflectionPropertyDispatcher.invoke(ReflectionPropertyDispatcher.java:154)
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.ReflectionPropertyDispatcher.push(ReflectionPropertyDispatcher.java:127)
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.push(AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.java:70)
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.push(AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.java:70)
    at org.linkki.core.ui.aspects.ButtonInvokeAspectDefinition.lambda$initModelUpdate$7e820d24$1(ButtonInvokeAspectDefinition.java:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:706)
    ... 56 more
```

when I change the automatically generated annotation of hausratZusatzdeckungen to FetchType.EAGER, I get a different error:

```
com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager$RpcInvocationException: Unable to invoke method click in com.vaadin.shared.ui.button.ButtonServerRpc
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:159)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:116)
    
...

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:155)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method buttonClick in org.linkki.core.ui.aspects.ButtonInvokeAspectDefinition$$Lambda$300/0x000000080082a840 failed.
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:726)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:399)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:363)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1190)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:384)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.ObjectRetrievalFailureException: Object [id=33] was not of the specified subclass [org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.model.hasurat.HausratGrunddeckung] : loaded object was of wrong class class org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.model.hasurat.HausratZusatzdekung; nested exception is org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=33] was not of the specified subclass [org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.model.hasurat.HausratGrunddeckung] : loaded object was of wrong class class org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.model.hasurat.HausratZusatzdekung
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:313)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.findById(Unknown Source)
    at org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.HrService.findAngebotById(HrService.java:25)
    at org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.view.VertragView.enter(VertragView.java:37)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.performNavigateTo(Navigator.java:778)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.lambda$navigateTo$9a874efd$1(Navigator.java:702)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.ViewBeforeLeaveEvent.navigate(ViewBeforeLeaveEvent.java:54)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.View.beforeLeave(View.java:79)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.runAfterLeaveConfirmation(Navigator.java:730)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:701)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:678)
    at org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.pmo.AngebotSectionPmo.send(AngebotSectionPmo.java:86)
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.InvokeMethod.invoke(InvokeMethod.java:61)
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.PropertyAccessor.invoke(PropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.ReflectionPropertyDispatcher.invoke(ReflectionPropertyDispatcher.java:154)
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.ReflectionPropertyDispatcher.push(ReflectionPropertyDispatcher.java:127)
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.push(AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.java:70)
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.push(AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.java:70)
    at org.linkki.core.ui.aspects.ButtonInvokeAspectDefinition.lambda$initModelUpdate$7e820d24$1(ButtonInvokeAspectDefinition.java:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:706)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=33] was not of the specified subclass [org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.model.hasurat.HausratGrunddeckung] : loaded object was of wrong class class org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.model.hasurat.HausratZusatzdekung
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceAlreadyLoaded(Loader.java:1582)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2204)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.loadByUniqueKey(EntityLoader.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2122)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.performTwoPhaseLoad(AbstractRowReader.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3967)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:639)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1133)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:992)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:529)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:54)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy149.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 87 more
```

So the way I understand it is that what was loaded from the Database was an instance of "HasuratZusatzdeckung" and not "HausratGrunddeckung", which is what I actually wanted. I find this very strange because I don't even have a "HausratZusatzdeckung" saved in the database, but only a "HausratGrunddeckung". Is the problem that I manually changed the annotation that was generated by the faktor ips code generator from FetchType.LAZY to FetchType.EAGER? Also, for the annotation of the attribute "hausratGrunddeckung" I added the CascadeType.ALL to the originally generated annotation. Is that a problem? If you could help me understand why this error occured and how to fix it, I would be very grateful.

the code for my `HausratGrunddeckung` is

```java
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("HRG_DECKUNG")
@IpsPolicyCmptType(name = "hasurat.HausratGrunddeckung")
@IpsAttributes({ "beitragGemaessZahlweise" })
@IpsAssociations({ "HausratVertrag" })
@IpsConfiguredBy(HausratGrunddeckungstyp.class)
@IpsDocumented(bundleName = "org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.model.modell-label-and-descriptions", defaultLocale = "de")
public class HausratGrunddeckung extends Deckung {

    /**
     * Diese Konstante enthaelt den Namen der Beziehung hausratVertrag.
     * 
     * @since 0.0.1
     *
     * @generated
     */
    public static final String ASSOCIATION_HAUSRAT_VERTRAG = "hausratVertrag";

    /**
     * Diese Konstante enthaelt den Namen der Eigenschaft beitragGemaessZahlweise.
     * 
     * @since 0.0.1
     *
     * @generated
     */
    public static final String PROPERTY_BEITRAGGEMAESSZAHLWEISE = "beitragGemaessZahlweise";

    /**
     * Membervariable fuer das Parent-Objekt: HausratVertrag.
     * 
     * @since 0.0.1
     *
     * @generated
     */
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = HausratVertrag.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "VERTRAG_ID")
    private HausratVertrag hausratVertrag;
...
}
```

the code for my `HausratZusatzdeckung` is

```java
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("HRZ_DECKUNG")
@IpsPolicyCmptType(name = "hasurat.HausratZusatzdekung")
@IpsAttributes({ "versSumme" })
@IpsAssociations({ "HausratVertrag" })
@IpsConfiguredBy(HausratZusatzdekungstyp.class)
@IpsDocumented(bundleName = "org.linkki_framework.fips.Hausrat_linkki_app.model.modell-label-and-descriptions", defaultLocale = "de")
public class HausratZusatzdekung extends Deckung {

    /**
     * Diese Konstante enthaelt den Namen der Beziehung hausratVertrag.
     * 
     * @since 0.0.1
     *
     * @generated
     */
    public static final String ASSOCIATION_HAUSRAT_VERTRAG = "hausratVertrag";

    /**
     * Diese Konstante enthaelt den Namen der Eigenschaft versSumme.
     * 
     * @since 0.0.1
     *
     * @generated
     */
    public static final String PROPERTY_VERSSUMME = "versSumme";

    /**
     * Membervariable fuer das Parent-Objekt: HausratVertrag.
     * 
     * @since 0.0.1
     *
     * @generated
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = HausratVertrag.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "VERTRAG_ID")
    private HausratVertrag hausratVertrag;
...
}
```

the model classes from which the code was generated look like this:

`Deckung`: the parent of `HausratGrunddeckung` and `HasuratZusatzdeckung`
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The screenshots and code you show look good to me, SINGLE_TABLE would be my strategy of choice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the method where you load the `Angebot` with `@Transactional` so that there is a session existing when lazy loading the assocation. The exception tells you that you are trying to lazy load the association without a transaction (session) with `could not initialize proxy - no Session`.

I suggest you dig into [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/) by one of the Hibernate maintainers Vlad Mihalcea where he shows the best way to deal with `LazyInitializationException`s. Eager fetching is definetly not the way to go, in fact it is actually [considered a code smell](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/). Apart from the `join fetch` approach described by Vlad (where you need a JPQL query), you could also use Spring Data JPAs `EntityGraph` annotation to fetch certain associations eagerly ([examples here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs)).

Regarding your second problem: I don't really understand what you mean by "automatically generated annotation". A Java annotation can't be generated automatically or added during runtime, it needs to be placed before compiling your code. You could try omitting the `targetEntity` attributes in your association annotations, I have never needed this attribute so far and I don't think that you need it as the Javadoc states that `Optional only if the collection property is defined using Java generics.`. Could you also show your code for the `HausratGrunddeckung` and `HausratZusatzdekung` class?

Comment: with "automatically generated annotations" I mean the annotations that the faktor ips generator code generated in the java code. So what I meant is that the @OneToOne annotation for the hausratGrunddeckung was generated by the faktor ips generator, and I changed it to add the cascadeType. I'm sorry that that was unclear. I edited the question to clarify it a bit. I also added code for the classes "HausratGrunddeckung" and "HausratZusatzdeckung" (not all of the code because the classes are many hundred likes long, and mostly irrelevant).

Comment: And thank you so much for the info about the LasyInitializationException, and the articles. It was very interesting and I learned a lot of useful stuff that I had no idea about.

Comment: Also, about the "org.hibernate.WrongClassException", I went into the model view of the "HausratGrunddeckung" and "HausratZusatzdeckung" and in the "JPA Entity Information" section changed the value of "Ableitungstrategie" from "SINGLE_TABLE" to "JOINED_SUBCLASS". That seems to have fixed the problem. But is there another way of doing it? Becuase if that is the only way, I don't get the point of the option of "SINGLE_TABLE". And thank you for the answer about the LazyInitializationException. the EntityGraph annotation fixed it for me

Comment: @jneu sorry I didn't notice your last comment, is your question still unanswered? :)